# get results with the same field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to get documents that the value of the "name" field repeats in 2 documents. how can I accomplished that?

Data example:

```
{
"name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe"
},
{
"name": "John",
"last_name": "Mark"
},
{
"name": "Jasmine",
"last_name": "llass"
},
{
"name": "Jonah",
"last_name": "Hill"
},
{
"name": "Leonardo",
"last_name": "DeC"
},
```

Desired output:

```
{
"name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe"
},
{
"name": "John",
"last_name": "Mark"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with a `terms` aggregation and a `top_hits` sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```